# Static method proxies in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I come from the Laravel world, and this framework offers a really handy feature called "Facades".

Bascially, a Laravel facade allows you to statically call any method on a class in order to instantiate it.

Consider the following class:

```
class Route {
  method?: string;
  path?: string;
  middleware?: CallableFunction[]
 
  get(path: string) {
    this.method = 'GET'
    this.path = path

    return this;
  }

  middleware(callables: CallableFunction[]) {
    this.middleware = callables

    return this
  }
}
```

Now, I haven't made the `get` or `middleware` methods static, however, I'd like my API to work with either of these scenarios:

```
const route1 = Route.get('/dashboard').middleware([auth])

const route2 = Route.middleware([auth]).get('/profile')
```

Notice I have not used the `new` keyword here.

I've read up on proxies and whatnot. To give you a better idea of what I'm looking for, consider a class like this:

```
class Route {
  method?: string;
  path?: string;
  middleware?: CallableFunction[]

  static get(path: string) {
    return new this.get(path)
  }
 
  get(path: string) {
    this.method = 'GET'
    this.path = path

    return this;
  }

  static middleware(callables: CallableFunction[]) {
    return new this.middleware(callables)
  }

  middleware(callables: CallableFunction[]) {
    this.middleware = callables

    return this
  }
}
```

Ideally I would like it so I don't need to declare static and non-static methods like this, however I'm not sure what other way to do it.

What would the best approach be for solving this?

Comment: Do you only want instance methods to turn into static methods? What about instance properties (that aren't functions)

Comment: Also `this.middleware =` is odd when you have a function also called `middleware` in the same instance.

Comment: @NickParsons when a static method is called, i'd like it to instantiate a new instance and then call the non-static version of that method. make sense?

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. But I’m asking about instance properties? If new Router().path returns a string, should Rourer.path also return a string? (ie: should instance properties also become static properties).

Comment: How should this also behave for classes with a constructor? Or is that not a valid scenario?

Comment: Also I think your middleware property might be a mistake, it conflicts with the method name

Comment: Really this just isn't idiomatic JS/TS. You'd not use a `class` but simply write `const route1: Route = {method: 'get', path: '/dashboard', middlewares: [auth]}; const route2: Route = {middlewares: [auth], {method: 'get', path: '/profile'};`. Only once this becomes repetitive you'd introduce a factory function `makeGetRoute`.

Comment: Why do you want the code to interact this way, why not use `new`?